# Chrome extension - Write to local storage of a different domain

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

How can I write to a local storage of a different domain. The idea is that I need my chrome extension to write something in the local storage and when the user visits the associated website, site site can read the contents of the local storage. I am trying to do a sync between the user's personal data without having to store them in the server.

Answer (score 13):

[Content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/) have direct acccess to a page's localStorage.

If you want to store a value for a specific domain, just open a window or frame, then write to the window/page's local storage.

1. Pick your favorite option to activate the page:

- [`chrome.tabs.create`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs#method-create) to create an inactive tab, perhaps in the non-active window found by using [`chrome.tabs.query`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#method-query).
- The experimental `offscreenTabs` API (experimental, so not ready for use in production). See some of the [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:me%20%5Boffscreentabs%5D) I posted on SO.
- Create an IFrame and insert it in the current page.
- `window.open` (not recommended...)

When you decide to open a page, pick one which is light-weight. `/robots.txt` is usually a good choice: It exists on most sites, *and* it is a plain text file.

2. Activate the content script for the page. You can either use the manifest file and make use of the [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/) APIs, or add a callback to the `chrome.tabs.create` method which programatically inserts a content script ([`chrome.tabs.executeScript`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#method-executeScript)).

Here's a simple example. It requires the `tabs` API because I'm using `chrome.tabs.executeScript`. Furthermore, the origin you want to access should also be added to the permissions list.

```
chrome.tabs.create({
    active: false,
    url: 'http://stackoveflow.com/robots.txt'
}, function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
        code: 'localStorage.setItem("key", "value");'
    }, function() {
        chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id);
    });
});
```

---

### Update (2022)

Since [`Manifest version 3`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/) the [`chrome.tabs.executeScript` API was replaced with the `chrome.scripting.executeScript` API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/#executing-arbitrary-strings), hence the code above can be changed to be like this:

```
function saveToLocalStorage() {
    localStorage.setItem("key", "value");
}

chrome.tabs.create({
    active: false,
    url: 'http://stackoveflow.com/robots.txt'
}, function(tab) {
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: {tabId: tab.id},
        func: saveToLocalStorage,
    }, function() {
        chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id);
    });
});
```

And please note, you need to add the `"scripting"` permission to your `manifest.json` file in order to use this API.

Comment: Certainly this looks like a workable solution. Although the problem I have right now is I need to do it from a background page. Creating an intactive tab will display something to the user. Offscreen tabs dont work with background pages. Window.open() obviously is not a solution. I will however try the iFrame one and let you know how it goes.

Comment: A bit late here, but you don't need content scripts if you control the domain you want to write to (as in OP's case). Just host a tiny .html with a script that reads messages and writes them to localStorage (you can verify domain to prevent abuse), and then create an iframe pointing to that script, and send over the data via regular `frame.contentWindow.postMessage`.

Answer (score 2):

I think the only solution to do this is via script injection due to cross domain restrictions.

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL("script.js");
s.onload = function() {
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
};
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
```

Add a file `script.js` to your extension accessing the other sites localStorage, you have to add `script.js` to "web_accessible_resources" in your manifest file.

Note that the script is automatically removed after the script was completely loaded, so make sure that the code you want to execute is contained in a self executable function.